# Using filenames with spaces and gawk

Tags: bash, gawk

I have a list of files I would like to process with gawk. Here is my command:

```
ls -1 *.wma | gawk '{printf("ffmpeg -i %s track4-%s.mp3\n",$0, $1);}'
```

But since the original filenames contain spaces, I get commands like

```
ffmpeg -i 02 Track 2.wma track4-02.mp3
```

which do not work as the spaces are not escaped. Any ideas how to get this right?

The expected output should be

```
ffmpeg -i 02\ Track\ 2.wma track4-02.mp3
```

Comment: perhaps you are looking for: http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs

Answer (score 0):

It's a [useless and buggy use of `ls`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls), try this instead using [glob](/questions/tagged/glob) :

```
for file in *.wma; do
    mp3=$(sed -r 's@([0-9]+)\s+Track\s+[0-9]+\.wma@track4-\1.mp3@' <<< "$file")
    ffmpeg -i "$file" "$mp3"
done
```

---

`ls` is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Use globs or find instead. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: But I not just want to replace wma by mp3. See updated question. Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: this does not seem to work unfortunately. I get commands like `ffmpeg -i 01 Track 1.wma`.

Comment: Nope, ffmpeg gives output `Unable to find a suitable output format for ''`.

Comment: Does a simple test command without spaces works ? Test it. Again, that works for me (archlinux and ffmpeg 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

As it seems to me that there is no easy way to get rid of the spaces in filenames to do such seemingly simple transformation of filenames, I cam up with a three line solution that works for me in python:

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob("*.wma"):
    print "ffmpeg -i {0} track4-{1}.mp3".format(filename.replace(' ','\ '),filename[:2])
```

I took me 2 minutes to do this in python. Bash seem to be not appropriate for this simple task.