# how do I define a filename suffix using gawk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to retrieve files archived on [Fairlight CMI](https://petervogelinstruments.com.au/images/Fairlight_CMI-30A_flyer_Feb2011.pdf) floppy disks four decades ago. There are many disks each with up to 80 files with different file extensions so the process needs to be automated. I use `grep` to extract a list of `filenames`, like so :

```
    $ grep Sounddsk2.img ls -a1 > filenames
```

and `gawk` to identify different file types based on their affix. A short sample of `filenames` can look like this

```
    bass.co
    bass.ss
    bass.vc
    flute5.co
    flute5.ss
    flute5.vc
    guitar.co
    guitar.ss
    guitar.vc
```

`gawk` will be used to output names of files ending in `.ss` from `filenames` into a directory called `ss` (based on answers to my earlier question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67564271/2348597)) *(accepted answer still open and yes, I'm still learning)*

```
    $ gawk '/^([a-zA-Z0-9])\.ss$/' filenames > ss
```

What I need to know is how to use `gawk` to make a directory named `ss` where I can save `.ss` files extracted from the disk image. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639280/2348597) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18242904/2348597) looked promising but the answers led nowhere.

In my second attempted `gawk` script, `filenames` is scanned for files ending in `.ss` and record separators (i.e. `.`) are counted. If `tally` is not zero, the script makes a directory named `ss` where extracted `.ss` files will be saved (eventually).

I have tried to detach the suffix from the file name by defining `.` as the record separator but this is probably not the right way to do it because the command line *below* does not work if `ss` also appears in the file name.

```
    $ gawk ‘BEGIN{RS=“[.]”; filetype= “ss”; tally=0}  index($1, “ss”){tally++} END{print tally; mkdir ss}’ filenames
```

And in the next version of the command below, `gawk` cannot read the test condition it needs to make the `ss` directory

```
    $ gawk ‘BEGIN{RS=“[.]”; filetype= “ss”; tally=0}  index($1, “ss”){tally++} END{if (tally >0) {mkdir ss}}’ filenames
```

So my questions are :

1. how do I define the filename suffix `ss` using `gawk` ?
2. how do I test the condition necessary to create a directory named `ss` ?

---

**Note**

What is being saved in these examples are file names not the actual files. Having a list of file names will be used to automate the following command line where the executable `a` will `get` each `archivedfile` from the floppy disk image to make a `localfile`, like so

```
    $ a Sounddsk2.img get archived-file local-file.
```

I hope this all makes sense. Any suggestions for improvement are most welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk is a tool to manipulate text. The tool to manipulate (create/destroy) files (and processes) is a shell. You're trying to use the wrong tool for your job.

It sounds like this is what you're trying to do (untested):

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    sfx="${file##*.}"
    mkdir -p "$sfx" &&
    touch "$sfx/$file"
done < filenames
```

or if you really only want the `.ss` files then (again untested):

```
sfx='ss'
grep "\.${sfx}$" filenames |
xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c 'mkdir -p '"$sfx"' && touch '"$sfx"'/{}'
```

If neither of those is what you're trying to do then please edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: Ed, this is exactly what I need. Choosing the wrong tool explains why I had so much trouble. Thanks